# Expression in Debugger shows correct value of calculation, but value is rounded when assigning to variable

Tags: type-conversion, stm32cubeide

I read 16 Bit two's complement sensor data byte after byte via I2C with a STM32, so I have to stick the High- and Low-Byte back together and convert this number to a float to get the real value.
My expression in C for this is

```
// Convert temperature value (256 LSBs/°C with +25°C Offset)
float temp = (tmpData[1] << 8 | tmpData[0])/256.0 + 25.0;
```

When I use the debugger of the STM32CubeIDE to check the calculation, the expression shows the correct conversion of the data (see screenshot). But the value assigned to the temp variable is always 25! It seems to me like the first term of the expression is always assumed to be 0 or something? I already tried a direct cast of the term in brackets to float, but that does not change anything.

Can anybody point me to the problem? Why is the debugger showing the correct value, but the code is assigning a wrong one?

---

The expressions in the screenshots below are captured by howering the mouse over the corresponding part of the above code line in debug mode.

**Fig. 1: Complete expression of calculation (gives result as expected)**
[image]

**Fig. 2: tmpData content (original two Bytes)**
[image]

**Fig. 3: Result of byte shifting and sticking**
[image]

**Fig. 4: temp result (always 25, even when expression above showes the expected value)**
[image]

*temp* is only a volatile for the moment, because I don't use that value yet and the compiler optimizes it out.

Comment: your debugger does not work - or it always shows decimal value

Comment: Try to change the optimization level to -O0 or -Og. Maybe simple this code was not yet executed

Comment: I already had set it to -Og, now I changed to -O0 -> No difference. So weird that it works for you! I updated the image in the question again to show details of temp. Actually the binary representations makes me think that it shows the "float" as an int...?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, new morning, new intuition...

The problem wasn't with this code line from the question, but (typ. Murphy) with the stuff I did not post. The I2C is read via DMA to the array and at the point I wanted to do the conversion the peripheral was not done yet. That's why the array elements were always empty when the code accessed them, but at the time I checked the values in the debugger the I2C peripheral had finished the transmission and I saw the expected values.

So the solution is to check if the peripheral is still busy...

Answer (score 0):

many issues in this single line of code.

1. `tmpData[1] << 8` has to be `(((uint16_t)tmpData[1]) << 8)`. If you shift byte 8 times the result will be zero (standard says undefined). You probably got the warning about it.
2. 256.0 & 25.0 are `double` values and the result will also be `double` then converted to the `float`. You shuold use 256.0f and 25.0f.

you can see the difference here: https://godbolt.org/z/Cm-S8T

Comment: I changed the code according to your corrections, but that does not change the output. And despite that I can't quite follow why the debugger is already showing the correct value.

Comment: it is not possible. How do you check the value of the `temp`? What are the tempData values? Yuo fo not provide the informations needed

Comment: I check the values by howering the mouse over the variable or expression in the debug mode. I updated the question with more detailed infos.

Comment: @jusaca it works fine for me. Click on the value in the expressions and see what is displayed below. (detailed info hex, obral, default etc)

Comment: I wrote an answer, because I finally figured it out... Thanks for the help and the tip, that it works fine for you! Got me thinking if the problem might be in another part of the code.